# ASP.NET Core MVC: IFormFile return Null when uploaded file is large

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a student project for C# Course implemented in ASP.NET Core MVC. Its file upload website, smaller files uploads flawlessly (65 mb, more or less) but large files as for example, 600 mb movie the `IFormFile` is null. I use .NET 6.0.

Uploading logic is implemented in MovieController -> https://dpaste.org/PBgks (a variable "file" is null) and CSHTML view uploadfile is here -> https://dpaste.org/25mOS

My project passed but I want to solve this bug once and for all

PS: If I forgot to mention some crucial info to solve this problem, please feel free to remind me.

Sorry for my rusty English.

UPDATE #1: After repeating a uploading process with larger files, it magically uploads (I had to click on upload button a dozen times). It's really weird.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to apply `RequestFormLimits` attribute and set the [MultipartBodyLengthLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.formoptions.multipartbodylengthlimit?view=aspnetcore-6.0), like below?

```cs
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 6104857600)] 
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file, int id)
{
    // your core here...
}
```

In additional, if you are running under the IIS set `maxAllowedContentLength` parameter in the `web.config`. For the ASP.NET Core MVC project this file doesn't added automatically, but it still needed for the IIS and should be added manually.

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4147483648" /> 
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

Configuring the `FormsOptions` parameters through the `startup.cs` file:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<FormOptions>(o =>
    {
        o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue; 
    });

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Comment: Yep, no progress

Comment: @KristianOravec: See my additional remark about the `maxAllowedContentLength` parameter. It is required to use `RequestFormLimits` attribute and set the  `maxAllowedContentLength` parameter in the `web.config` file.

Comment: This newest version does not use web.config file anymore, now there is only appsettings.json file. Content is listed here -> https://dpaste.org/fx2QF

Comment: @KristianOravec: The ASP.NET Core MVC project doesn't adding the `web.config` automatically, but this file still needed when an application running under the **IIS**. Therefore the `web.config` file should be added manually to the project. When running under the **Kestrel** server enough to set `FormOptions` parameters in the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find a way to change the `maxRequestLength` property. Although I don't think the problem with it when the default value is only 4MB or has been changed by you before.

Answer (score 0):

code for `_storageServices.UploadFile` is not provided. though i think you code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file, int id)
    {
        var viewMod = new UploadViewModel();
        viewMod.Id = id;
      
        try
        {
            await _storageServices.UploadFile(file, id).ConfigureAwait(false);
            ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";               
            return View(viewMod);
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
            return View(viewMod);
        }
    }
```

looks like you are just passing it to the **service** which then updates the database.

if your intention is to upload it to some `dir` then use this code:

```
try
{   
    //this will upload the file to directory
    using (var stream = new FileStream("upload path", FileMode.Create))
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }

    //your code for entry of file in database
    await _storageServices.UploadFile(file, id).ConfigureAwait(false);
    ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";               
    return View(viewMod);
}
catch
{
    ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
    return View(viewMod);
}
```

Comment: https://dpaste.org/uMzrs here is code for _storageServices.UploadfFIle. But I don't really catch your solution